# Different results applying merge in R over individual data frames and over one list of data frames

Tags: r, lapply

Hi everybody I am working with a list of data frames in R and I want to merge them one by one. I found one solution is using `Reduce()` function with `merge()` but I don't get the same result when I merge one by one data frame. My list of data frames is `global` and It has the next structure (I include `dput()` version of my list in final part):

```
global
$a1
   ID Value Products z1
1 001     1        3  1
2 002     2        2  1
3 003     3        0  1
4 004     4        1  1
5 005     5        1  1
6 006     6        6  1
7 007     7        7  1
8 009     8        1  1
9 010     9        1  1

$a2
    ID Value Products z2
1  001     1        3  2
2  002     2        2  2
3  003     3        0  2
4  004     4        1  2
5  005     5        1  2
6  006     6        6  2
7  011    10        5  2
8  012    11        5  2
9  007     7        7  2
10 009     8        1  2
11 010     9        1  2

$a3
    ID Value Products z3
1  001     1        3  3
2  002     2        2  3
3  012    11        5  3
4  013    11        1  3
5  014    11        2  3
6  003     3        0  3
7  004     4        1  3
8  005     5        1  3
9  006     6        6  3
10 007     7        7  3
11 009     8        1  3
12 010     9        1  3
13 011    10        5  3

$a4
    ID Value Products z4
1  001     1        3  4
2  002     2        2  4
3  012    11        5  4
4  013    11        1  4
5  014    11        2  4
6  003     3        0  4
7  004     4        1  4
8  005     5        1  4
9  006     6        6  4
10 007     7        7  4
11 009     8        1  4
12 010     9        1  4
13 011    10        5  4
14 015    12        3  4
15 016    12        3  4

$a5
    ID Value Products z5
1  001     1        3  5
2  002     2        2  5
3  003     3        0  5
4  004     4        1  5
5  016    12        3  5
6  017    14        2  5
7  005     5        1  5
8  006     6        6  5
9  007     7        7  5
10 009     8        1  5
11 010     9        1  5
12 011    10        5  5
13 012    11        5  5
14 013    11        1  5
15 014    11        2  5
16 015    12        3  5
17 018    14        2  5
```

I am merging all data frames with their previous data frames in `global` and for this I used the next code to create a new list named `listag`:

```
listag=Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x,y[,c(1,4)],by=intersect(names(x)[1],names(y)[1]),all.x=TRUE),global,accumulate=TRUE)
```

I used the argument `all.x=TRUE` in `merge()` because I want to keep in each data frame their orginal number of rows (`a1`=9,`a2`=11,`a3`=13,`a4`=15,`a5`=17). After of this I separated `global` in individual data frames to check last code works fine and I found differences. To separate data frames I used this code:

```
list2env(global, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

I got my five data frames. Now I am going to show what I want with data frames `a4` and `a5`. First I used next code to merge `a4` with `a1`,`a2`,`a3` and `a4`:

```
Final41=merge(a4,a1[,c(1,4)],by=intersect(names(a4)[1],names(a1)[1]),all.x=TRUE)
Final42=merge(Final41,a2[,c(1,4)],by=intersect(names(Final41)[1],names(a2)[1]),all.x=TRUE)
Final43=merge(Final42,a3[,c(1,4)],by=intersect(names(Final42)[1],names(a3)[1]),all.x=TRUE)
Final4=merge(Final43,a4[,c(1,4)],by=intersect(names(Final43)[1],names(a4)[1]),all.x=TRUE)
```

The result of this code is:

```
Final4

    ID Value Products z4.x z1 z2 z3 z4.y
1  001     1        3    4  1  2  3    4
2  002     2        2    4  1  2  3    4
3  003     3        0    4  1  2  3    4
4  004     4        1    4  1  2  3    4
5  005     5        1    4  1  2  3    4
6  006     6        6    4  1  2  3    4
7  007     7        7    4  1  2  3    4
8  009     8        1    4  1  2  3    4
9  010     9        1    4  1  2  3    4
10 011    10        5    4 NA  2  3    4
11 012    11        5    4 NA  2  3    4
12 013    11        1    4 NA NA  3    4
13 014    11        2    4 NA NA  3    4
14 015    12        3    4 NA NA NA    4
15 016    12        3    4 NA NA NA    4
```

Where the argument `all.x=TRUE` is working fine because I keep the original number of observations in `a4`(15). When I extract the 4th element of `listag` I got this:

```
f4l=listag[[4]]
f4l

  ID  Value Products z1 z2 z3 z4
1 001     1        3  1  2  3  4
2 002     2        2  1  2  3  4
3 003     3        0  1  2  3  4
4 004     4        1  1  2  3  4
5 005     5        1  1  2  3  4
6 006     6        6  1  2  3  4
7 007     7        7  1  2  3  4
8 009     8        1  1  2  3  4
9 010     9        1  1  2  3  4
```

For `merge()` in `Reduce()` function I am considering also `all.x=TRUE` but I don't get the same result and the number of observations is wrong. I would like to get after applying the combination of `Reduce()` and `merge()` the result of `Final4`. It is the same for the rest of data frames of `listag` after applying `Reduce()` and `merge()` combined over `global`. I would like to get this result for each data frame in `listag`(in this case for 4th data frame it would be):

```
   ID  Value Products  z1 z2 z3  z4
1  001     1        3  1  2  3    4
2  002     2        2  1  2  3    4
3  003     3        0  1  2  3    4
4  004     4        1  1  2  3    4
5  005     5        1  1  2  3    4
6  006     6        6  1  2  3    4
7  007     7        7  1  2  3    4
8  009     8        1  1  2  3    4
9  010     9        1  1  2  3    4
10 011    10        5 NA  2  3    4
11 012    11        5 NA  2  3    4
12 013    11        1 NA NA  3    4
13 014    11        2 NA NA  3    4
14 015    12        3 NA NA NA    4
15 016    12        3 NA NA NA    4
```

I don't know what is wrong in my code when I combine `Reduce()` and `merge()`. I am considering `all.x=TRUE` equal when I make the merge one by one data frame. Could you help me with this. Maybe I have to add another argument in the combination of `Reduce()` and `merge()` to get my result or there is other way like use `lapply` or `llply` from `plyr` package over `global`. The `dput()` version of global is the next:

```
structure(list(a1 = structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "003", 
"004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010"), Value = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Products = c(3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 6, 7, 1, 1), z1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("ID", "Value", "Products", 
"z1"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame"), a2 = structure(list(
    ID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "011", "012", 
    "007", "009", "010"), Value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 
    7, 8, 9), Products = c(3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 6, 5, 5, 7, 1, 1), 
    z2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Value", "Products", "z2"), row.names = c(NA, 11L), class = "data.frame"), 
    a3 = structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "012", "013", "014", 
    "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011"), 
        Value = c(1, 2, 11, 11, 11, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), 
        Products = c(3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 6, 7, 1, 1, 5), 
        z3 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), .Names = c("ID", 
    "Value", "Products", "z3"), row.names = c(NA, 13L), class = "data.frame"), 
    a4 = structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "012", "013", "014", 
    "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", "015", 
    "016"), Value = c(1, 2, 11, 11, 11, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    10, 12, 12), Products = c(3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 6, 7, 1, 
    1, 5, 3, 3), z4 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4)), .Names = c("ID", "Value", "Products", "z4"), row.names = c(NA, 
    15L), class = "data.frame"), a5 = structure(list(ID = c("001", 
    "002", "003", "004", "016", "017", "005", "006", "007", "009", 
    "010", "011", "012", "013", "014", "015", "018"), Value = c(1, 
    2, 3, 4, 12, 14, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 14), 
        Products = c(3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 
        2, 3, 2), z5 = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
        5, 5, 5, 5, 5)), .Names = c("ID", "Value", "Products", 
    "z5"), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("a1", 
"a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"))
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things:

*First, it is normal that your *Reduced merge* and your manual merge* give different results since they are not performed in the same order. The Reduce processes 1:4, and for a reason I do not quite understand, in your manual merges your perform 4,1,2,3,4.

Second, the difference that you observe is that the a4 table has additional IDs, and they are lost in the Reduced merge, because you use all.x=TRUE, but the a4 table came as the "y" table. So you should use all=TRUE  instead:

```
listag <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y[, c(1, 4)],
          by = intersect(names(x)[1], names(y)[1]), all = TRUE), global)
```